# Meringue - Dry Crisp And Impossibly Delicate

Tags: egg-whites, meringue

I am looking for a recipe for an impossibly dry/crisp baked meringue.  The baked meringue medallions, once cooled, are almost like oak log ash, and the medallions cannot be picked up by their edges, that's how delicate they are.  If you touch the dry meringue with your finger, it dents.  I'm talking about a white, dry crisp meringue cookie that is dry/crisp all the way through, and barely holds its form/shape when you pick it up, and melts on the tongue.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about?  Am I crazy?

Comment: Welcome to the site @JesuSpectre. Recipe requests are off-topic on this site. If you have a recipe that isn't working for you or are asking about technique then it would be on-topic. You could edit this question to change it from a recipe request to asking about what factors effect the consistency of a meringue and it would be fine.

Comment: Have you had this previously, or just want to make your meringues more delicate?

Answer (score 2):

As far as the meringue goes, you're probably aware there are several kinds, hard, soft, and italian. These are described here: https://www.incredibleegg.org/eggcyclopedia/m/meringue/.

Obviously you want a hard meringue, which is the driest kind. Beyond that, the article says the main factor affecting dryness is the humidity of the baking environment. If you live in a desert your dessert will be drier. A dehumidifier would probably help. It states that the moisture is primarily absorbed into the sugar so reducing the amount of sugar might also help.

Finally, the article also states that baking at a low temperature for a longer time dries the meringue more thoroughly and evenly.